# How to set the key-value pairs of a HashMap final in Java 11?

Tags: java, hashmap, final, java-11

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Foo {
    private final Map<String, Integer> exits;

    public Foo() {
        this.exits = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getExits() {
        return exits;
    }

    public void show() {
        for (String i : exits.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + exits.get(i));
        }
    }
}

class Bar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.getExits().put("A", 1);
        foo.getExits().put("B", 2);
        foo.show();
        //Okay, no problem.
        //Output: A: 1
        //        B: 2
        foo.getExits().replace("A", 10);
        foo.getExits().remove("B");
        foo.show();
        //Output: A: 10
    }
}
```

I have declared `exits` in class `Foo` as `final` so that it cannot be referred to another `HashMap` once it has been assigned in the constructor. I also want to set every elements in `exits` as final, so that once I put a key-value pair in `exits`, it cannot be modified or removed by any means. I have tried the following approach (Note the change in the `getExits()` method and `main()` method):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Foo {
    private final Map<String, Integer> exits;

    public Foo(Map<String, Integer> exits) {
        this.exits = exits;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getExits() {
        return new HashMap<>(exits);
    }

    public void show() {
        for (String i : exits.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + exits.get(i));
        }
    }
}

class Bar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> temp=new HashMap<>();
        temp.put("A", 1);
        temp.put("B", 2);
        Foo foo = new Foo(temp);

        foo.show();
        //Okay, no problem.
        //Output: A: 1
        //        B: 2
        foo.getExits().replace("A", 10);
        foo.getExits().remove("B");
        foo.show();
        //Output: A: 1
        //        B: 2
    }
}
```

Question 1:
Why wouldn't it work if I declared `exits` as  `private final Map<final String, final Integer> exits;`?
Question 2:
Is there any other way by which I can achieve the same?
P.S: I am new to Java, so correct me if there are any mistakes since I might be mixing C++ concepts with Java.

Comment: You want either `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` or an immutable version like Guava's `ImmutableMap`.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- could you explain that to me in more detail?

Comment: Read about Collections.unmodifiableMap [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29).

Comment: Final just makes the reference final, so you cannot point it at a new map. It isn't the same as c's const which makes the data immutable. You might be able to achieve what you're after by creating a duplicate Map that your class doesn't expose. Eg. when you call getExits you return an unmodifiableMap (which is just a view of your existing map). edit: as in your extra example.

Comment: Or Java 12's `Map.copyOf()`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1: `Map<final String, final Integer>` is not valid syntax in Java. I don't know what you mean by it. This use reminds me of `const` modifier in C++, but final is not const, and in any case String and Integer are already immutable

Answer 2: Your `getExits` method returns a modifiable copy of the map. That works, but it's more common to return an *unmodifiable view* of the data structure. It is a lightweight decorator that throws an exception if the caller attempts to make changes, but otherwise calls methods in the original map. The caller has to copy the map itself if it wants one.

```
public Map<String, Integer> getExits() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(exits);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first question:
actually in the second code when you are calling getexits everytime it returns a different shallow copy(new Hashmap).shallow copy is a different copy of exits where you can only modify the returned map,not the original one you declared at foo class. so,foo.getexits() are totally different map that you return,it is modifying new hashmap each time,not the temp one or foo(temp).if you code like this,

```
    temp.replace("A",10);
    temp.remove("B");
    foo.show();
```

instead of,

```
    foo.getExits().replace("A", 10);
    foo.getExits().remove("B");
    foo.show();
```

then it will print the same output as your first program does.(it will also modify).
Shortly,your second code is not modifying because everytime you are returning and modifying a new hashmap which have no relation with temp.so,those will not affect your foo(temp).

second question:
if you really want not to modify anything in the main class,then you may code like following at the getexits() method in the second program:

```
  return Collections.unmodifiableMap(exits);
```

and don't change anything of the second program as you does.then it will throw

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

whenever you want to modify using foo.getexits() and prevent you from modifying that.but you can still modify temp separately as it has no relation with the getexits method.i am also a beginner like you,but I have tried to answer your question with my small knowledge. hope,it will help